# Country code lookup for each line in a CSV file

Tags: c#, performance, linq, csv

I'm trying to write a program that has a `for` loop, inside of which I have lambda expression to get a certain value. The loop has about 20,000 iterations. Including this lambda expression increases the execution time significantly. If I include it, it takes about 20 mins for the loop to finish; without it, it takes just 10 seconds.

Here's what the lambda expression looks like:

```
code = countries.Find(c => c.ISO2Code == iso2).Country_Code
```

Same expression using Linq:

```
code = (from a in countries
        where a.ISO2Code == iso2
         select a.Country_Code).First();
```

Here, the list `countries` is cached for the loop starts, so it's not like the query is made to the DB. What's the reason for this time costly expression?

Here's the full code for the loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    if (!timer.IsRunning)
        timer.Start();

    var d = line[i];
    var row = d.Replace("\n", "");
    var values = row.Split(',');

    if (values.Length < 3)
    {
        return;
    }


    if (values.Length >= 2)
    {
        if (values[2] != null && values[2] != "")
        {
            string contactno = Utils.RemoveSpecialCharacters(values[2]);


            if (model.NumberFormat == 1)
            {
                Country cntry =
                    countries.Where(x => x.Country_Code == model.CountryCode)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

            contactno = utils.GetValidNumberWithCountryCode(contactno, cntry.ISO2Code);
            }

            int? code = null;
            try
            {
                contactno = "+" + contactno;
                try
                {
                //this is commented
                ph = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(contactno, "US");
                if (phoneUtil.isValidNumber(ph))
                {
                    string iso2 = phoneUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(ph);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(iso2))
                    {
                        code = countries.Find(c => c.ISO2Code == iso2).Country_Code;
                        //code = (from a in countries
                        //        where a.ISO2Code == iso2
                        //        select a.Country_Code).First();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
                {
                    code = null;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            if (code != null && utils.IsValidNumber(contactno))
            {
                contactno = utils.GetValidNumber(contactno);

                bool match = false;
                foreach (var item in existingList)
                {
                    if (item.ContactNumber.ToString() == contactno)
                    {
                        ExistingnumberCount += 1;
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!match)
                {
                    validNumberCount += 1;
                    Contact_List cl = new Contact_List();
                    cl.Customer_Code = model.Customer_Code;
                    try
                    {
                        string fname = values[0];
                        if (fname.Length > 50)
                        {
                            fname = fname.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.First_Name = fname;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        string lname = values[1];
                        if (lname.Length > 50)
                        {
                            lname = lname.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.Last_Name = lname;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        string CF1 = values[3];
                        if (CF1.Length > 50)
                        {
                            CF1 = CF1.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.CF1 = CF1;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        string CF2 = values[4];
                        if (CF2.Length > 50)
                        {
                            CF2 = CF2.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.CF2 = CF2;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        string CF3 = values[5];
                        if (CF3.Length > 50)
                        {
                            CF3 = CF3.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.CF3 = CF3;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        string CF4 = values[6];
                        if (CF4.Length > 50)
                        {
                            CF4 = CF4.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.CF4 = CF4;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }

                    cl.CountryCode = code;
                    cl.Contact_No = contactno.Replace("+", "");
                    cl.Is_Active = true;
                    cl.Create_Date = DateTime.Now;
                    cl.Opt_Status_Code = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        string Contact_Email = values[7];
                        if (Contact_Email.Length > 50)
                        {
                            Contact_Email = Contact_Email.Substring(0, 50);
                        }
                        cl.Contact_Email = Contact_Email;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                InvalidnumberCount += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Total Execution Time: " + (double)(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000));
    Debug.WriteLine("No of iterations completed: " + i);
}
```

Comment: Please ask for your accounts to be merged: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Now that you've added a whole **working** program you should change your title to be more descriptive of the purpose of the code.

Comment: You have so many insane `try/catch` blocks there. Why don't you check the indexes before accessing the array or getting the substrings?

Comment: I find your claim to be extraordinarily dubious. `Find()` only has to find the first matching item, where as `Where().First()` must find all matches and *then* get the first of those. Best case, this is optimized to be equivalent to a `Find()`, but there really shouldn't be a case where `Find()` is less efficient.

Comment: @RubberDuck `Where().First()` does not need to find all matches.  `Where()` constructs a lazy enumerable (and doesn't actually find anything) and `First()` merely enumerates the first item out of it.  As soon as the first item is found, it will stop.  There will be some additional overhead compared to `Find()` what with the extra objects and method calls involved, but it definitely won't look at more items than it has to.

Comment: I assumed as much after I thought about it @Kyle, but there's still no reason I can think of that would make `Find(foo)` slower than `First( _ => _.foo == foo)`.

Comment: @RubberDuck Indeed, there's no reason it should be.  They will both do the same exact thing: iterate over the collection, apply the supplied delegate, return the current value when that delegate returns true.

Comment: Instead of using `Timer` to do performance tuning, download a C# profiler.  That will make your job _significantly_ easier.

Comment: You should use this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact to merge your user accounts.

Comment: @Kyle This requires more context to be able to verify: based on your claim that `Find` is slower than LINQ, I ran a benchmark of `.Find(x => x.ISO2Code == iso2)` vs `.First(x => x.ISO2Code == iso2)` vs `(from x in items where x.ISO2Code == iso2 select x.CountryCode)`, and the `Find` was *the fastest* (I was having it located *the last* record in each list). The actual timings: `352us/ea`, `467us/ea`, `441us/ea`, in order, with BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: @Kyle Also, in the case of `Find`, based on my research it uses an indexer (instead of an iterator, which is what `Where` and `First` use) which means it should be *slightly* faster than `.Where().First()` in most (probably all) scenarios (by the way: `.First()` can take the same predicate as `.Where()`, so you can eliminate `.Where()` altogether if you immediately call `.First()`).

Comment: @EBrown I never once claimed that `Find` is slower than LINQ.  Where did you get that idea?  In fact, I specifically said that there would be more overhead for LINQ because it's creating more objects and is a tad more indirect.  In large part their performance will be comparable and any differences will only show up in rather extreme situations.

Answer (score 41):

Your loop is close to 200 lines, that's waaaay too long. That's long for a full class, let alone one method, let alone part of one method.

---

Why do you use `for (int i = 1; i < count - 1; i++`) when you don't do anything with `i`? Why not use `foreach(var line in lines)`? Oh wait, I see, you've called your collection `line` -- a bad name, since this doesn't tell me it is a collection of lines.

---

You assign `d`, a name that conveys absolutely nothing, only to use that to execute `var row = d.Replace("\n", "");`. Why not do that in one line?

---

Everything inside `if (values.Length >= 2)` should be moved to a separate method; matter of fact make that everything inside `if (values[2] != null && values[2] != "")`. Also, don't you know about `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`?

---

`values[0]`, `values[1]`, `values[2]`, etc. are meaningless. It would be far better to convert each line into a class with properly named properties.

---

Then suddenly we encounter `if (model.NumberFormat == 1)`, yet `model` is nowhere defined. I assume this comes from outside the `for` loop? If so, then why is this code located here?

---

Property names should not contain an underscore: `Country_Code`.

---

Logic like "retrieve `contactno`", "retrieve `code`", etc. should all be a method of their own.

---

You are using `try...catch` waaaay too much. I mean, this is just nuts:

```
int? code = null;
try
{
    contactno = "+" + contactno;
    try
    {
        //this is commented
        ph = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(contactno, "US");
        if (phoneUtil.isValidNumber(ph))
        {
            string iso2 = phoneUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(ph);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(iso2))
            {
                code = countries.Find(c => c.ISO2Code == iso2).Country_Code;
                //code = (from a in countries
                //        where a.ISO2Code == iso2
                //        select a.Country_Code).First();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        code = null;
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Do you seriously expect `contactno = "+" + contactno;` to throw an exception?

---

Why is there a comment saying `//this is commented`?

---

This:

```
bool match = false;
foreach (var item in existingList)
{
    if (item.ContactNumber.ToString() == contactno)
    {
        ExistingnumberCount += 1;
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

can basically be replaced by `match = existingList.Any(x => x.ContactNumber.ToString() == contactno);`.

---

At that point I'm not even halfway through and I have to give up. You need to seriously refactor this code. Each property you need to retrieve should have its own method, and in 99% of those cases there shouldn't be an empty `try...catch` block.

WRT your question: consider converting countries to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, e.g. `var countryCodeByIso2 = countries.ToDictionary(x => x.ISO2Code, x => x.Country_Code);` and then use `TryGetValue()`. But please, first refactor your code.

Comment: I joined this community just so that I could up-vote this answer.

Comment: Maybe add `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` to your vocabulary too, this doesn't just check for empty strings, but all whitespace strings as well.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using linq lookups for the lists you should map your data into dictionaries, which are MUCH faster to access specific instance of your data, memorywise you might take a hit but the mapping is just onetime.

```
var countries = new List<Country>();
var countriesByCode = countries.ToDictionary(c => c.Country_Code, c => c);

Country cntry;
if (countriesByCode.TryGetValue(countryCody, out cntry))
{
    contactno = utils.GetValidNumberWithCountryCode(contactno, cntry.ISO2Code);
}
```

Consider this sample on what is the performance difference.

```
var stringList = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000).Select(s => new Tuple<int, string>(s, s.ToString())).ToList();
var dictionary= stringList.ToDictionary(s => s.Item1, s => s);

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (var i = 50000; i > 0; i--)
{
    var t = stringList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Item1 == i);
    if (t != null)
    {
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

sw.Restart();
for (var i = 50000; i > 0; i--)
{
    Tuple<int, string> t;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(i, out t))
    {
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

It takes about 20seconds to perform the lookups through the list, but under a millisecond to perform the same with dictionary lookups. Memory is consumed a bit more however.

Comment: I doubt there are 50000 countries but I tested your code with just 500 and that is consistent with performance reported by OP.

Comment: List lookup is O(N), dictionary / hash lookup is O(1). Unless N is guaranteed very small every time, using a dictionary is always going to win, and the memory overhead is rarely if ever a problem these days.

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> if (values.Length < 3)
> {
>     return;
> }
>
>
> if (values.Length >= 2)
> {
> ```

How should in the second `if` the `values.Length` ever be anything than `> 2` ? That second `if` is superflous and doesn't add anything but a level of intendation to the code and makes it less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that countries is cached
You could close the DB connection before the loop to test

Move this to before the loop

```
if (!timer.IsRunning)
    timer.Start();
```

-

```
values[2] != null && values[2] != ""
```

could be

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(values[2])
```

Duplicate catch

Some indents wrong

How would this ever fail?
You know Length >= 2

```
try 
{   string fname = values[0];
    if (fname.Length > 50)
    {
       fname = fname.Substring(0, 50);
    }
    cl.First_Name = fname;
 }
```

Go with

```
 cl.First_Name = values[0].Length > 50 ? values[0].Substring(0, 50) : values[0];

 if(values.Length >= 3)
 {
     cl.CF2 = values[4].Length > 50 ? values[4].Substring(0, 50) : values[4];
 }
```

You create a new Contact_List and do not actually use it for anything

```
Contact_List cl = new Contact_List();
```

convert to double after you divide adds not value

```
(double)(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
```